# Temporal tables VS SCD 2

Tags: sql-server, etl, data-warehouse, scd2, historical-db

The temporal table can use it to replace the SCD type2 in a data warehouse ?.
I use temporal table in azure sql database.

Comment: How would you generate your surrogate keys?

Answer (score 3):

Typically no.  Temporal tables are a good fit for staging tables, and can be used as a source to create slowly-changing dimensions if needed in a dimensional model.

The whole point of a dimensional model is to make writing queries easy.  In SCD the fact table still has a simple single-column foreign key to the dimension table.  So you get a historically accurate dimension values for each fact rows without complicating the queries.

To get the same result from a temporal table you'd have to join both the main table and the archive table, and filter them on both the business key of the dimension and the validfrom and validto dates.

Also temporal tables only support system versioning, which means that the validfrom and validto are always refer to the clock of the database server.  In a data warehouse you might want to use some other temporal reference in your data to model your SCD.

Comment: why it's not enough ? you have the date validfrom and validto to establish the history. no ?

Comment: see update to answer.

Comment: Here are some good references that talks about "historical reporting" scenarios specially, the use of bitemporal table design.

* https://tdan.com/the-case-against-slowly-changing-dimensions-part-one/18505
* https://tdan.com/the-case-against-slowly-changing-dimensions-part-two/18960